# Asgardeo UserManagementAPI: Inconsistent Error in Asgardeo Create User/Bulk Create User

Tags: wso2-asgardeo

We were trying to create a user in Asgardeo using UserManagementAPI

***POST** https://api.asgardeo.io/t/asgardeo/scim2/Bulk*
Request Body:

```
{
  "failOnErrors": 0,
  "schemas": [
    "urn:ietf:params:scim:api:messages:2.0:BulkRequest"
  ],
  "Operations": [
    {
      "method": "POST",
      "bulkId": "ezYkd",
      "path": "/Users",
      "data": {
        "schemas": [
          "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:core:2.0:User"
        ],
        "userName": "DEFAULT/olie@rtzassociates.com",
        "emails": [
          {
            "primary": true,
            "value": "olie@rtzassociates.com"
          }
        ],
        "name": {
          "familyName": "Olie",
          "givenName": "Santos"
        },
        "urn:scim:wso2:schema": {
          "askPassword": true
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Response Body:

```
{
  "schemas": [
    "urn:ietf:params:scim:api:messages:2.0:BulkResponse"
  ],
  "Operations": [
    {
      "bulkId": "ezYkd",
      "method": "POST",
      "response": "{\"schemas\":[\"urn:ietf:params:scim:api:messages:2.0:Error\"],\"scimType\":\"invalidValue\",\"detail\":\"The minimum length of password should be 8.\",\"status\":\"400\"}",
      "status": {
        "code": 400
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

However if you try the same request on
***POST** https://api.asgardeo.io/t/asgardeo/scim2/Users*
Request Body:

```
{
  "userName": "DEFAULT/olie@rtzassociates.com",
  "emails": [
    {
      "primary": true,
      "value": "olie@rtzassociates.com"
    }
  ],
  "name": {
    "familyName": "Olie",
    "givenName": "Santos"
  },
  "urn:scim:wso2:schema": {
    "askPassword": true
  }
}
```

Response Body:

```
{
  "emails": [
    "olie@rtzassociates.com"
  ],
  "meta": {
    "created": "2023-03-21T00:46:31.404271Z",
    "location": "https://api.asgardeo.io/t/ascension/scim2/Users/6f355967-706d-4b08-b1a0-633a8bccd151",
    "lastModified": "2023-03-21T00:46:31.727462Z",
    "resourceType": "User"
  },
  "schemas": [
    "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:core:2.0:User",
    "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:enterprise:2.0:User",
    "urn:scim:wso2:schema"
  ],
  "roles": [
    {
      "display": "everyone",
      "value": "7e044e9c-7b9b-47bf-b542-098362f8ac86",
      "$ref": "https://api.asgardeo.io/t/ascension/scim2/Roles/7e044e9c-7b9b-47bf-b542-098362f8ac86"
    }
  ],
  "name": {
    "givenName": "Santos",
    "familyName": "Olie"
  },
  "id": "6f355967-706d-4b08-b1a0-633a8bccd151",
  "userName": "DEFAULT/olie@rtzassociates.com",
  "urn:scim:wso2:schema": {
    "accountLocked": "true",
    "accountState": "PENDING_AP",
    "lockedReason": "PENDING_ASK_PASSWORD",
    "userSource": "DEFAULT",
    "idpType": "Local",
    "isReadOnlyUser": "false"
  }
}
```

What is weird is, when we successfully create a user using the **Users Endpoint**, we can now create a user using the **Bulk Endpoint**
***POST** https://api.asgardeo.io/t/asgardeo/scim2/Bulk*
Request Body:

```
{
  "failOnErrors": 0,
  "schemas": [
    "urn:ietf:params:scim:api:messages:2.0:BulkRequest"
  ],
  "Operations": [
    {
      "method": "POST",
      "bulkId": "ezYkd",
      "path": "/Users",
      "data": {
        "schemas": [
          "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:core:2.0:User"
        ],
        "userName": "DEFAULT/olie+1@rtzassociates.com",
        "emails": [
          {
            "primary": true,
            "value": "olie+1@rtzassociates.com"
          }
        ],
        "name": {
          "familyName": "Olie+1",
          "givenName": "Santos"
        },
        "urn:scim:wso2:schema": {
          "askPassword": true
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Response Body:

```
{
  "schemas": [
    "urn:ietf:params:scim:api:messages:2.0:BulkResponse"
  ],
  "Operations": [
    {
      "bulkId": "ezYkd",
      "method": "POST",
      "location": "https://api.asgardeo.io/t/ascension/scim2/Users/a13a6e05-ed92-4071-87a9-aeeaede4fd30",
      "status": {
        "code": 201
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

We were expecting that on the initial call to
***POST** https://api.asgardeo.io/t/asgardeo/scim2/Bulk* would already successfully create the user instead of having to call the **Users Endpoint**
Request Body:

```
{
  "failOnErrors": 0,
  "schemas": [
    "urn:ietf:params:scim:api:messages:2.0:BulkRequest"
  ],
  "Operations": [
    {
      "method": "POST",
      "bulkId": "ezYkd",
      "path": "/Users",
      "data": {
        "schemas": [
          "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:core:2.0:User"
        ],
        "userName": "DEFAULT/olie@rtzassociates.com",
        "emails": [
          {
            "primary": true,
            "value": "olie@rtzassociates.com"
          }
        ],
        "name": {
          "familyName": "Olie",
          "givenName": "Santos"
        },
        "urn:scim:wso2:schema": {
          "askPassword": true
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue might be caused due to the fact that we generate a random password for a user if he/she is created with the `askPassword` option. Basically what happens is as follows:

- User creation request is initiated with the `askPassword` option.
- Since the `askPassword` option is available in the request, Asgardeo generates a random password for that user.
- Unfortunately, sometimes the randomly generated password might not adhere to the password policy defined in the Asgardeo side hence causing this issue.

We will need to check this behavior further to confirm the above. If the above mentioned is the reason, we should possibly add a suitable fix for it. We will keep you updated on this thread.